# size of the windows phone 8.1 silverlight application

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-8.1

Actually, we did one music app in windows phone using silverlight frame work,after the completion of the application, the xap file is too large (600mb). So how to decrease the size of the application and we are using songs which is in our local folder.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: If the songs have to be local? Download them from server when needed is better. But if they have to be local. You can try to compress them by using other audio format.

Comment: Thanks chris,but our requirement should be in .wav format only... can you suggest some tools to compress the audio fies...?

Comment: 'WAV' is a lossless and uncompressed format. Can you use "MP3" instead of it? Maybe this link will be helpful. http://superuser.com/questions/457025/reduce-wav-file-size